# Show patch coordinates in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm using the following code at the command center to show the coordinates of a random patch:

```
ask one-of patches [show pycor pxcor]
```

but I get an Expected command error, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`show` takes a single argument, and you are passing it two- `pxcor` and `pycor`. It depends how you want to display this, but depending on your goal you could do:

```
observer> ask one-of patches [show pycor show pxcor]
(patch -15 0): 0
(patch -15 0): -15
```

Or more likely

```
observer> ask one-of patches [show list pycor pxcor ]
(patch 16 8): [8 16]
```

Answer (score 1):

`show` [takes only one input](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#show), so you need the patch to perform two separate actions. `ask one-of patches [show pycor show pxcor]` will print both coordinates:

```
observer> ask one-of patches [show pycor show pxcor]
(patch -9 10): 10
(patch -9 10): -9
```

If for some reason you don't like the fact that this results in the output being shown on two lines, you can use `word` and have it reported as a single string: `ask one-of patches [show (word pycor " " pxcor)]`:

```
observer> ask one-of patches [show (word pycor " " pxcor)]
(patch -9 4): "4 -9"
```

**Edit** Using a list, as in Luke's answer, looks certainly more elegant than using a string with manually-inserted spaces... what a dumb choice lol